# São “tem” e “têm”, e “vem” e “vêm” homófonas?

Tags: pronúncia, diferenças-transatlânticas

Eu sempre falei *tem* e *têm* do mesmo modo, o mesmo com *vem* e *vêm*, sem exceção, e sempre achei que fossem homófonas em qualquer lugar, mas já ouvi que *têm* se fala /tãeãe/ ou /tããe/, ou algo assim, em Portugal. Não sei se é verdade.

Então pergunto: são *tem* e *têm*, e *vem* e *vêm* homófonas em qualquer lugar? Pergunto principalmente do Brasil e Portugal.

Comment: Pois falar *tem* e *têm* do mesmo modo é esquecer o acento circunflexo. Fica um tem-tem, que são dois.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não, em Portugal **não são** homófonas.

"Tem" soa "tãim", "têm" soa "tãim-ãim";

"vem" soa "vãim", "vêm" soa "vãim-ãim";

Vide transcrição fonética:

https://european-portuguese.info/pt/ipa#tem%20t%C3%AAm

> tem: tɐ̃j
>
> têm: ˈtɐ̃jɐ̃j

Comment: `"têm" soa "tãim-ãim"` — não fazia ideia disso.

Answer (score 2):

**Saudações!**

Sou brasileiro nativo e espero te auxiliar com minha resposta. Lembrando que ela é válida para o PT-BR.

Apesar de as palavras com acentos possuírem o mesmo significado e pronúncia do que as sem acento, suas colocações em frases escritas são diferentes. Ao falar, não há nenhuma diferença entre elas, porém um cuidado especial deve ser tomado na hora de escrever.

**Vem e tem (sem acento) -**
Estas palavras derivadas do verbo "vir" e "ter", respectivamente, são usadas para representar uma terceira pessoa do singular, ou seja, algo ou alguém que não seja o locutor. Basicamente refere-se à um único indivíduo/objeto que está vindo de algum lugar ou que possui algo.

**Exemplo 1:** "Ele vem de outro continente."

**Exemplo 2:** "Ele tem outra nacionalidade."

É muito importante observar que estas palavras sem acento são APENAS PARA SE REFERIR A UMA ÚNICA INSTÂNCIA, ou seja, SINGULAR.

**Vêm e têm (com acento) -** Apesar de possuírem o mesmo significado de suas variações sem acento, estas servem para indicar o plural da terceira pessoa, ou seja, duas ou mais instâncias e algo ou alguém, sendo que o locutor NÃO PODE fazer parte deste conjunto. Quando o locutor está inserido, utiliza-se a palavra "nós temos, nós viemos".

**Exemplo 1:** "Eles vêm de muito longe."

**Exemplo 2:** "Eles têm outra forma de se comunicar."

**Resumindo:**

As palavras "vem" e "tem" sem acento são usadas para representar apenas uma terceira pessoa do singular.

As palavras "vêm" e "têm" com acento são usadas para representar uma terceira pessoa do plural.

A pronúncia é a mesma, porém a colocação escrita é diferente.

Espero ter ajudado. Bons estudos.

Comment: Aqui, um falante nativo de pt-BR.  Noto que estico levemente as vogais acima quando acentuadas.

Comment: @Centaurus, também faço isso, mas me pergunto se não é um efeito psicológico.

Comment: Creio que isto pode causar a sensação de estar falando "veem", que deriva do verbo "ver". Apesar de não estar incorreto, recomendo fortemente NÃO esticar a vogal para evitar este tipo de conflito.

Comment: @Schilive   Não creio que seja um efeito psicológico.  Foi assim que aprendi na escola.  No século passado.

Comment: Não é natural pronunciar errado, mas antes de aprender, você não sabe pronunciar certo. Já vi professores tratarem palavras de formas diferentes, mas nem todos lecionam português. A questão é que eles aprenderam há muito tempo, e naquela época escrevia-se de formas diferentes se não me engano. Acho que cada um fala de um jeito diferente, e cabe ao ouvinte entender. Pode analisar os efeitos no cérebro através do braile e da linguagem de sinais, mas geralmente não é nada do que pensamos, e ainda estamos longe de entender porque um estica se acha que está errado e outro achando não estar.

Comment: @renanlinux, não há pronúncia errada, mas há a pronúncia culta. A pronúncia culta de *vêm* é ou /vẽẽ/ ou /vẽ/. A pronúncia culta de *vêem* é /veẽ/. Para quem fala *vêm* como /vẽẽ/, *vem*, *vêm* e *vêem* se diferem foneticamente entre si; para quem fala *vêm* como /vẽ/, *vem* e *vêm* são foneticamente iguais, diferindo-se foneticamente ambas de *vêem*.